# Iterating model in Razor template fails to render

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Attempting to render a collection and it silently fails to output anything. I search for a similar problem on SO and found nothing that described my issue.

I am absolutely certain the collection is not empty. Debugging in the controller and the view shows items in the collection of the type I set.

I've attempted these approaches, and both render nothing.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Messages)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(msg => item.MessageBody)
}

@foreach (var item in Model.Messages)
{
    @Html.Display(item.MessageBody)
}
```

This renders the value as expected

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Messages)
{
    @item.MessageBody
}
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: @AdamTuliper  There was no error as the helper seemed to be losing the scope or some such and was 'empty'. Depending on what was happening and where, the collection always had data. That is why I was so confused. Why was it coming up empty initially? I do not know, only that forcing it to list in the controller seems to have made the data 'stick' as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird, works perfectly fine for me:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public string MessageBody { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel
        {
            Messages = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => new Message
            {
                MessageBody = "message " + x
            })
        });
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel

@foreach (var item in Model.Messages)
{
    <div>@Html.DisplayFor(msg => item.MessageBody)</div>
}
```

I suspect that your `Messages` collection is empty or something. Can't think of another rational explanation as I am unable to reproduce your issue as shown in my answer.

As a side note I would use display templates to avoid writing any loops. So your `Index.cshtml` view simply becomes:

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Messages)
```

and then you write a corresponding display template (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Message.cshtml`) which wil automatically be rendered for each item of the `Messages` collection of your view model:

```
@model Message

<div>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MessageBody)</div>
```

Comment: Hello Darin, Thanks for the quick response. The collection is definitely not empty, as I state in my original post. This was a test to try out mvc 3 and razor. I like the display template idea, thx.

Comment: @ZombieThread, did you try my answer? See that it works? I don't know what might cause yours not to work. Post a complete example allowing us to reproduce the problem. The same way I posted a complete and working example allowing to show that this actually should work.

Comment: I am unable to write the comment I wish here due to length( not that long at all. The SO interface is extremely unfriendly. I wanted to post what I found as the solution, was not allowed. Tried to do it here in the comments and was not allowed. The entry of code is also difficult if there is more than a few lines. Why not use BB code or something that works properly? White space? Is this Python? :-)

I'll try and add a secomd comment.

Comment: I have it working using the same view code now. It seems that Entity Framework's lazy loading may be the issue. I'm still not sure if I am right, with all layers of magic going on, but forcing a toList() on the initial returned result sets Messages property ( Messages is a collection property of a User object ) made the Html.DisplayFor work as expected. I had a foreach in the controller that operated on the Messages collection and would have thought that iteration would have caused it to be loaded and thus the view would have no problems. That was a wrong assumption I guess.